# how to find the first and last 1 in each row of a bw matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix

```
bw=[
0 0 1 1 1 0;
1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 1 1 0 0;
0 0 0 1 1 1
];
```

I want to find the column numbers of the first 1 that occurs in each row and the last 1. The column numbers should be displayed in two different vectors as shown below.
The output for the above matrix should be:

```
first = [3 1 2 4]
last  = [5 5 4 6]
```

Comment: please show us what you tried. This is not a codewriting service. We gladly help to debug your failed attempt, but an attempt should have been made.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
bw=[0 0 1 1 1 0;1 1 1 1 1 0;0 1 1 1 0 0;0 0 0 1 1 1];
for i = 1:size(bw,1)
    first(i) = find(bw(i,:),1);
    last(i) = find(bw(i,:),1,'last');
end
```